# WildFly JMS issue: "Consumer is closed"

Tags: java, jms, wildfly, activemq-artemis

I have one application deployed in WildFly 19 and one standalone Java application which is used to send/receive messages in the queue. This application works fine, but when I tried with the load testing, I'm getting "Consumer is closed" exception like below from the Java application. After that my Java application not able to send and receive any messages from the queue.

```
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQObjectClosedException: AMQ119017: Consumer is closed
        ... 11 common frames omitted
2021-03-18 08:46:16,949 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR c.v.d.h.c.dip.jms.ResponseConsumer - Error while waiting for Response from Queue
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: AMQ119017: Consumer is closed
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.checkClosed(ClientConsumerImpl.java:952) [artemis-core-client-2.6.3.jbossorg-00014.jar:2.6.3.jbossorg-00014]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.receive(ClientConsumerImpl.java:195) [artemis-core-client-2.6.3.jbossorg-00014.jar:2.6.3.jbossorg-00014]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.receive(ClientConsumerImpl.java:379) [artemis-core-client-2.6.3.jbossorg-00014.jar:2.6.3.jbossorg-00014]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.getMessage(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:211) [artemis-jms-client-2.6.3.jbossorg-00014.jar:2.6.3.jbossorg-00014]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.receive(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:132) [artemis-jms-client-2.6.3.jbossorg-00014.jar:2.6.3.jbossorg-00014]
        at com.verizon.delphi.hyperion.core.dip.jms.ResponseConsumer$1.run(ResponseConsumer.java:139) [classes/:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_112]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQObjectClosedException: AMQ119017: Consumer is closed​
```

Here is the standalone-full.xml for the Queue config

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:9.0">
    <server name="default">
        <statistics enabled="${wildfly.messaging-activemq.statistics-enabled:${wildfly.statistics-enabled:false}}"/>
        <security-setting name="#">
            <role name="guest" send="true" consume="true" create-non-durable-queue="true" delete-non-durable-queue="true"/>
        </security-setting>
        <address-setting name="#" dead-letter-address="jms.queue.DLQ" expiry-address="jms.queue.ExpiryQueue" max-size-bytes="10485760" page-size-bytes="2097152" message-counter-history-day-limit="10"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor"/>
        <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http" endpoint="http-acceptor-throughput">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
        </http-connector>
        <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-connector>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor" http-listener="default"/>
        <http-acceptor name="http-acceptor-throughput" http-listener="default">
            <param name="batch-delay" value="50"/>
            <param name="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
        </http-acceptor>
        <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0">
            <param name="buffer-pooling" value="false"/>
        </in-vm-acceptor>
        <jms-queue name="ExpiryQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/ExpiryQueue"/>
        <jms-queue name="DLQ" entries="java:/jms/queue/DLQ"/>
        <jms-queue name="probeRequestQueue" entries="jms/queue/probeRequestQueue java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/probeRequestQueue queue/probeRequestQueue" durable="true"/>
        <jms-queue name="probeResponseQueue" entries="jms/queue/probeResponseQueue java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/probeResponseQueue queue/probeResponseQueue" durable="true"/>
        <jms-topic name="serverStateTopic" entries="java:jboss/exported/topic/serverStateTopic"/>
        <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory" entries="java:/ConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm"/>        
        <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory" entries="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory java:/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory" connectors="http-connector" block-on-acknowledge="true" reconnect-attempts="-1" />
        <pooled-connection-factory name="activemq-ra" entries="java:/JmsXA java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" connectors="in-vm" reconnect-attempts="0" transaction="xa"/>
    </server>
</subsystem>​
```

Currently I'm struck with this issue and looking for the support. Thank you!

EDIT:

Producer class code :

```java
public class RequestValidator {
    
    private static final Logger L = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestValidator.class);
    private ServerStateListener listener;
    static final String REQUEST_QUEUE = "jms/queue/requestQueue";
    private long jmsProducerTimeToLive;
    
    public RequestValidator(ServerStateListener listener, Properties config) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.jmsProducerTimeToLive = Long.parseLong(config.getProperty("jms.producer.mgs.timetolive", "5000"));
    }
    
    public void messageReceived(RequestDto request, Object callback) throws Exception {
        
        final Connection connection = Util.getConnection();
        
        if (Util.isAlive(connection)) {
            Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(Util.getQueue(REQUEST_QUEUE));
            ObjectMessage requestMsg = session.createObjectMessage();
            requestMsg.setObject(request);
            producer.setTimeToLive(jmsProducerTimeToLive);
            producer.send(requestMsg);
            L.info("Request sent.....");
        } else {
            L.error("Unable to acquire Connection to MyApp");
            throw new OssException(OssExceptionType.ExceptFTOSSAppUnavailable, "Unable to acquire connection to MyApp");
        }
    }
}
```

Consumer Code :

```java
public class ResponseConsumer {
    
    private static final Logger L = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResponseConsumer.class);
    private final ExecutorService es;
    private SimpleResponseTransmitter responseTransmitter;
    private Connection connection;
    
    static final String RESPONSE_QUEUE = "jms/queue/responseQueue";
    
    private RunnableAdapter runner;
    private boolean connected;
    
    public ResponseConsumer(SimpleResponseTransmitter responseTransmitter)       {
        this.responseTransmitter = responseTransmitter;
        this.es = new ThreadPoolExecutor(5, 60, 60L,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
        reconnect();
    }
    
    public final void reconnect() {
        try {
            if (Util.isAlive(connection)) {
                return;
            }
            this.connected = false;
            this.connection = Util.getConnection();
            if (Util.isAlive(connection)) {
                connection.setExceptionListener(new ConsumerExceptionListener());
                L.info("Starting Response Consumer....");
                try {
                    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
                    
                    final MessageConsumer responseConsumer = session.createConsumer(Util.getQueue(RESPONSE_QUEUE));
                    connection.start();
                    this.runner = new RunnableAdapter() {
                        
                        public void run() {
                            while (isAllowedToRun()) {
                                try {
                                    final ObjectMessage message;
                                    if ((message = (ObjectMessage) responseConsumer.receive(30000)) != null) {
                                        es.submit(new ResponseBuilder(message));
                                    }
                                } catch (JMSException ex) {
                                    L.error("Error while waiting for Response from Queue", ex);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    this.connected = true;
                } catch (JMSException ex) {
                    L.error("Error in queue consumer", ex);
                }
                
            } else {
                L.error("Application NOT reachable for reading response queue");
            }
        } catch (JMSException ex) {
            L.error("Error creating JMS connection for queue consumer", ex);
        }
    }
}​
```

Other :

```java
class Util {
    private static final Logger L = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Util.class);
    private static final Object lock = new Object();
    private static TopicConnection topicConnection;
    private static Connection connection;
    protected static MyApplicationClient client;
    
    private static ConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory() {
    return client.lookup("java:/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory", ConnectionFactory.class);
     } 
     
    private static TopicConnectionFactory  getTopicConnectionFactory() {
    return client.lookup("java:/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory", TopicConnectionFactory.class);
     } 
     
     public static boolean isAlive(Connection connection) {
        try {
            return (connection != null && connection.getMetaData() != null);
        } catch (JMSException ex) {

            return false;
        }
    }
    public static Queue getQueue(String jndiName) {
        return client.lookup(jndiName, Queue.class);
    }

    public static Topic getTopic(String jndiName) {
        return client.lookup(jndiName, Topic.class);
    }
    public static Connection getConnection() throws JMSException {
        if (isAlive(connection)) {
            return connection;
        }
        synchronized (lock) {
            if (client.reconnect()) {
                final ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = getConnectionFactory();
                if (connectionFactory != null) {
                    connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(USERNAME,PASSWORD);
                    connection.start();
                }
            }
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

WildFly Admin Console - Request Queue detail:
[image: WildFly Admin Console - Request Queue detail]
WildFly Admin Console - Response Queue detail:
[image: WildFly Admin Console - Response Queue detail]

Comment: Can you elaborate on your "load testing"? How are you conducting your load testing? Why doesn't your application deal with the exception and re-initialize the consumer or connection? Are there any messages in the log which indicate any problems? Can you paste your client code?

Comment: @JustinBertram Load test is nothing but I'm sending n number of requests into the queue and it will get received from the app server end and returned the processed response back to the submitter. I have pasted the code as you requested.

Comment: @JustinBertram How to increase/decrease the number of consumers and set each queue expire time ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with the design of your consumer. In `reconnect` you're creating a `javax.jms.Session` instance and a `javax.jms.MessageConsumer` instance in a `try` block. Then you use the `MessageConsumer` instance in a `RunnableAdapter` instance. I assume this `RunnableAdapter` instance is going to be run later. However, the problem is that by the time the `RunnableAdapter` instance is actually run later the `Session` used to create the consumer will have fallen out of scope and may have even been garbage collected. This means the `Consumer` instance will not work. You should refactor your application so this doesn't happen.

Comment: Hi Justin, I tried closing the opened object but still the same issue occurs. When i check the Wildfly admin console for the queue status, found the below case.

I sent 95 requests into the request-q and 47 requests are still in process state and 48 processed response sent back to response-q.

Comment: What do you mean you, "tried closing the opened object"? The fact that it's being closed *is* the problem.

Comment: The 47 requests are kind of struck there and neither the request nor response queue count not getting updated

Comment: As far as I can tell your problems are caused by the way your client is written (which I explained in my answer).

Comment: I meant these sessionObj.close() and MessageConsumerObj.close() as it was not closed anywhere

Comment: Like I said, the fact that the `javax.jms.Session` is closed *is* the problem. That's true whether you close it explicitly or let it fall out of scope as you were doing previously.